Reflexive pronouns and prepositions of direction
Can you please explain the following?

She dragged it toward her. (Why not: She dragged it toward herself.)
He pulled her against him. (Why not: He pulled her against himself.)
I look around me. (But: I wrapped my arms around myself.)

Which sentence is correct?

He changed my opinion of him. Or, he changed my opinion of himself.

Thank you.

"She dragged it toward her" could contrast with "and away several times." "Toward herself" would mean something a bit different.

It's largely idiomatic and can sometimes subtly shift the point of view. She wrapped the blanket around her or she wrapped the blanket around herself. Looks like it might make for a nice prepositional verb test, though - she threw the blanket off herself - because throw off is a verb but wrapped around isn't??

ah - "This paper presents experimental work on the relative naturalness of
subject-oriented reflexives (herself) and pronouns (her) in English locative
prepositional phrases (e.g., Michele set a glass next to her/herself)." https://journals.linguisticsociety.org/proceedings/index.php/PLSA/article/download/5263/4886

Thank you, Phil.

Great questions! Let’s break down the use of reflexive pronouns and prepositions of direction in these examples: nystateofhealth

She dragged it toward her.

Explanation: “Toward her” is correct because “her” is the object of the preposition “toward.” Reflexive pronouns are used when the subject and the object are the same person or thing. In this case, “it” and “her” are different, so “herself” is not needed1.

He pulled her against him.

Explanation: Similar to the first example, “against him” is correct because “him” is the object of the preposition “against.” Since “her” and “him” are different, “himself” is not appropriate.

I look around me.

Explanation: “Around me” is correct here because “me” is the object of the preposition “around.” Reflexive pronouns are not used after prepositions of place.

I wrapped my arms around myself.

Explanation: This is correct because the subject “I” and the object “myself” are the same person. Reflexive pronouns are used here to indicate that the action is performed on the subject itself.

He changed my opinion of him. or He changed my opinion of himself.

Explanation: “He changed my opinion of him” is correct. Reflexive pronouns are not used when the subject and the object are different. In this case, “my opinion” is about “him,” not "himself"

Thank you so much. There is only one more question. Couldn't I say, "I wrapped my arms around me," and use the same logic as the previous explanation? “Around me” is correct because “me” is the object of the preposition “around.”  “My arms” and “me” are different, so “myself” is not needed.

In #1, the subject is "she", not "it". They're the same thing, so "herself" would be correct. "it" is the direct object, "her/herself" is the indirect object.

'She dragged it toward herself' and 'He pulled her against himself' are perfectly valid, more emphatic forms. See the Quirk et al reference at the duplicate.
